# Comparing an argument to a string when argument is a result of a command with etoolbox

Tags: macros, conditionals, etoolbox

I've got an example like that:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\ab}{a}

\newcommand{\aORb}[1]{%
        \ifstrequal{#1}{a}{"a" was given}{not a}, %
        \ifstrequal{#1}{b}{"b" was given}{not b}%
}

\begin{document}
 begin

     \aORb{\ab{}}

 end
\end{document}
```

And the output of that code is:

```
begin
not a, not b
end
```

However, if I put simply "a" or "b" as an argument to `\aORb` instead of `\ab{}` then it works fine.

Is there another command in `etoolbox` package that will allow me to do such a comparison correctly?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `etoolbox` manual states for `\ifstrequal` on page 17: (emphasis mine)

> Compares two strings and executes ⟨*true*⟩ if they are equal, and ⟨*false*⟩ otherwise.
>   The strings are **not expanded** in the test and the comparison is category code agnostic.

So you always compare the string “\ab{}” with “a” and “b”. If you want to allow macros as input you need to expand them manual:

```
\newcommand{\aORb}[1]{%
        \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{#1}{a}{"a" was given}{not a}, %
        \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{#1}{b}{"b" was given}{not b}%
}
```

This expands the first token of `#1` once before `\ifstrequal` is processed.

If you want to expand the input completely use:

```
\newcommand{\aORb}[1]{%
        \edef\mytemp{{#1}}%
        \expandafter\ifstrequal\mytemp{a}{"a" was given}{not a}, %
        \expandafter\ifstrequal\mytemp{b}{"b" was given}{not b}%
}
```

This expands the input completely using `\edef` and wraps it in braces, so only one `\expandafter` is enough.

Then you need to use `\aORb{\ab}` not `\aORb{\ab{}}`, because `\ab` doesn't take an argument the `{}` would stay and you would compare here “a{}” with “a” and “b”.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Is there a shorter way to do this?

Comment: It's already quite short IMHO, but you can write an own macro like `\newcommand\myifstrequal{\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter}` and then use it instead of `\ifstrequal`.

Comment: Yes, with that additional macro, it'll be really very short. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 5):

2018 Update.

*See* "The etoolbox Package," v2.5e (19 Aug 2018)

[The etoolbox Package (v2.5e)](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf)

On p.19:

> \ifdefstring{(*command*)} {(*string*)} {(*true*)}
>   {(*false*)}
>
> Compares the replacement text of a (*command*) to a 
>   (*string*) and executes (*true*) if they are equal, 
>   and (*false*) otherwise. Neither the (command) nor the
>   (*string*) is expanded in the test[,] and the
>   comparison is category code agnostic. Control sequence
>   tokens in the (*string*) argument will be detokenized
>   and treated as strings. This command is robust. Note
>   that it will only consider the replacement text of the
>   (*command*). For example, this test
>
> > \long\edef\mymacro#1#2{\string&}
> >
> > \ifdefstring{\mymacro}{&}{true}{false}
>
> would yield (*true*). The prefix and the parameters of
>   \mymacro as well as the category codes in the
>   replacement text are ignored.

Here's a short code example.

```
% TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% TeXShop (ver. 2.47) (Mac OSX 10.5.8)
% compliation method LaTeX pdfTeX

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[dvipsnames*, x11names, svgnames, hyperref]{xcolor}

\obeylines

% Create some quick \TeX commands for color-info parsing
\def\dfltColorModel
\def\dfltColor

% Get the system's default color
\AtBeginDocument{\colorlet{defaultcolor}{.}}

\begin{document}

Here's the xcolor step of obtaining the system's default color scheme:

% extract the color into Model and Color
\begin{verbatim}
\extractcolorspecs{.}{\dfltColorModel}{\dfltColor}
\end{verbatim}

\extractcolorspecs{.}{\dfltColorModel}{\dfltColor}

Default Color Model: \dfltColorModel

Default Color: \dfltColor

\bigskip

\begin{testcolors}[rgb,cmyk,hsb,HTML,gray]
\testcolor{.}
\end{testcolors}

\bigskip

Here's the comparison using \verb!{\ifdefstring}!

\bigskip

\begin{verbatim}
\ifdefstring{\dfltColorModel}{gray}{\textcolor{blue}{true}}{false}
\end{verbatim}

\ifdefstring{\dfltColorModel}{gray}{\textcolor{blue}{true}}{false}

\bigskip

The trial and err-roar time it's taken to accomplish this one simple comparison is a story for another time.

\end{document}
```

Here's the output.

[image]