# How do I use \ifcommandkey , or how do I check if a key was given?

Tags: conditionals, key-value

I'm trying to create a keycommand with optional arguments, but I can't get it to work. I looked at [Comparing an argument to a string when argument is a result of a command with etoolbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24922/comparing-an-argument-to-a-string-when-argument-is-a-result-of-a-command-with-et) and although the example there works, I can't get it to work for use with keycommand, nor can I get `ifcommandkey` to work as expected. I recently upgraded from Tex Live 2009 to Tex Live 2011 and in 2009, `ifcommandkey` was working.

In Tex Live 2011, how do I check whether a key was given or not?

Below is an example where I try different things. None have the desired effect; in the third call, I want the result to be something like "No spam. No eggs. No paper. No Salt", but I get "Has spam" in every run. Why?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{keycommand}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\myifstrempty{\expandafter\ifstrempty\expandafter}
\newkeycommand{\testkc}[spam,eggs,paper,salt][][0]{
\ifcommandkey{spam}{Spam: ``\commandkey{spam}''}{No spam}.
\ifcommandkey{eggs}{Eggs: ``\commandkey{eggs}''}{No eggs}.
\ifcommandkey{paper}{Paper: ``\commandkey{paper}''}{No paper}.
\ifcommandkey{salt}{Salt: ``\commandkey{salt}''}{No Salt}.
\ifcommandkey\expandafter{salt}{Salt: ``\commandkey{salt}''}{No Salt}.
\myifstrempty{\commandkey{spam}}{Not has spam}{Has spam}
\expandafter\ifstrempty{\expandafter{\commandkey{spam}}}{Not has spam}{Has spam}
}

\testkc[spam=bad, eggs=good, salt=horrid]

\testkc[paper=gold]

\testkc

\newcommand{\aORb}[1]{%
        \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{#1}{a}{"a" was given}{not a}, %
        \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{#1}{b}{"b" was given}{not b}%
}


\aORb{a}

\aORb{b}

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: result]

Comment: If you find the time, try the key commands and key environments of 'ltxkeys' package. If you encounter difficulties there, first email the package author.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## The `\ifcommandkey` approach

There is a bug in the definition of `\ifcommandkey` (2010/04/27 v3.1415). It is missing out one stage of expansion of the `\commandkey` (see the analysis in the section below), and as a result does not test the *value* of the key. (You will get TRUE even with an undefined key.) Try the following definition in the preamble after loading `keycommand`:

```
\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \catcode`\/=8 %
  \@firstofone
    {
      \endgroup
      \renewcommand{\ifcommandkey}[1]{%
        \csname @\expandafter \expandafter \expandafter 
        \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter  \expandafter
        \kcmd@nbk \commandkey {#1}//{first}{second}//oftwo\endcsname
      }
   }
```

## The `\ifstrempty` approach

The issue here is that you are not doing enough expansion for the `\ifstrempty` test. What you need to ensure it that the argument this receives is the value passed to the key, and not some intermediate form. Thus you need to expand `\commandkey` to the content it represents. Now, there are a three approaches for this type of thing. First, we could use `\edef`:

```
\newcommand\myifstrempty[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \edef\x{%
      \endgroup
       \noexpand\ifstrempty{#1}%
    }%
    \x
}
```

The problem with this is that you don't know what might be given for the key value, so the `\edef` may go wrong.

A more controlled approach is to use the correct number of `\expandafter`s. If you do

```
\show\commandkey
```

you'll find it expands to

```
\csname keycmd->testkc@#1\endcsname
```

inside your key-using macro. So to expand to the *value* of the key requires three expansions: the first to expand `\commandkey`, the second to expand the `\csname` primitive and the third to expand the resulting control sequence. Due to the way TeX expansion works, this leads to

```
\newcommand\myifstrempty{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifstrempty
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
 }
```

The third approach is to use the peculiar nature of `\romannumeral` to do what LaTeX3 would call a 'full' expansion. This is similar to doing an `\edef` but will halt cleanly on anything which cannot be expanded:

```
\newcommand\myifstrempty[1]%
  {\expandafter\ifstrempty\expandafter{\romannumeral -`0#1 }}
```

The later is useful in the current case as it cuts down on the number of `\expandafter` primitives required.

Comment: I've reported the issue to the package author

Comment: Thanks! This `\expandafter` stuff looks pretty complicated, makes me happy there are so many useful packages around that I don't feel the need to roll my own package (yet) :)

Comment: @gerrit Expansion is a tricky area, hence for example the LaTeX3 Project's work on a programming layer which deals with a lot of this.

Comment: It is 2020, almost 2021, and the patch is still needed! Absent author?

Comment: @hsmyers No change: package code has not been updated

Comment: Intervention necessary?

Comment: @hsmyers In what way? This is a bug that's been there for 10 years, and I doubt anyone really wants to pick up the package just to sort this (as it can be patched after-the-fact)

Comment: Good point. Simple cut and paste, which is easy enough to find.