# Need help to create a more flexible \cancel command that works inside an align environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, align, cancel

Please, consider the snippet below.

I would like to cancel out the two middle terms of equation (1) and to cancel to 1 the expression in between the braces in equation (2).

If I use `\cancel` and `\cancelto` from the `cancel` package, this results in a diagonal line starting too low and ending too high, as the expressions are very long. For small expressions, the results are good.

Some solutions to this problem were given in [Diagonal strikeout starting too low and ending too high](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20643/diagonal-strikeout-starting-too-low-and-ending-too-high). However, these solutions seem to work just for inline equations. For example, [the solution given by Speravir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156581/95438) seems nice, but if I use it inside the align environment, it changes the typeset of the term being cancelled in such a way that it differs from the other terms, as exemplified below, with the second term that I want to cancel.

Questions:

1. Would it be possible to adapt the above-mentioned solution to work inside the align environment?
2. Would it be possible to create an equivalent \hcancelto command, to be used in equation (2)?

Thanks!

p.s. I use the `yathesis` document class (to write theses in french) in the snippet to keep consistency with my document. Someone that doesn't have the `yathesis` class installed can use the book or article classes instead.

```
\documentclass[mainlanguage=english,babel={main=english,french,brazil},sepcorpaffilfrench={,~},sepcorpaffilenglish={,~},version=inprogress]{yathesis}
%\documentclass{book}
%\documentclass{article}
%
% If using XeLaTex or LuaLaTex
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%
% If using LaTex or PdfLaTex
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%
\usepackage{lmodern} % latin modern font
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel} % draw diagonal lines  ("cancelling" a term)
%
%%% Code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156581/95438 %%%
%
\usepackage{keycommand}
% Patch by Joseph Wright ("bug in the definition of \ifcommandkey (2010/04/27 v3.1415)"),
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35794
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\catcode`\/=8 %
\@firstofone
{
    \endgroup
    \renewcommand{\ifcommandkey}[1]{%
        \csname @\expandafter \expandafter \expandafter
        \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter
        \kcmd@nbk \commandkey {#1}//{first}{second}//oftwo\endcsname
    }
}
%--------%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newkeycommand{\hcancel}[hshiftstart=0pt,vshiftstart=0pt,hshiftend=0pt,vshiftend=0pt,color=red][1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(tocancel.base)]{
        \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (tocancel) {#1};
        \draw[\commandkey{color}] ($(tocancel.south west)+(\commandkey{hshiftstart},\commandkey{vshiftstart})$) --
        ($(tocancel.north east)+(\commandkey{hshiftend},\commandkey{vshiftend})$);
    }%
}%
%
%%% End of code %%%
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
&= \mp \cos^{2} \left[ 2\pi\left(  \frac{k}{2}t^{2} + f_{1}t + \varphi\right)\right] \int_{0}^{t} s_{i}\left( \tau\right) \sin \left[ 2\pi\left( kt + f_{1}\right)\tau\right] \, d\tau \\
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}} \cancel{\pm \frac{1}{2} \sin \left[ 4\pi\left(  \frac{k}{2}t^{2} + f_{1}t + \varphi\right)\right] \int_{0}^{t} s_{i}\left( \tau\right) \cos \left[ 2\pi\left( kt + f_{1}\right)\tau\right] \, d\tau} \\
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}} \hcancel{$\mp \frac{1}{2} \sin \left[ 4\pi\left(  \frac{k}{2}t^{2} + f_{1}t + \varphi\right)\right] \int_{0}^{t} s_{i}\left( \tau\right) \cos \left[ 2\pi\left( kt + f_{1}\right)\tau\right] \, d\tau$} \\
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}} \mp \sin^{2} \left[ 2\pi\left(  \frac{k}{2}t^{2} + f_{1}t + \varphi\right)\right] \int_{0}^{t} s_{i}\left( \tau\right) \sin \left[ 2\pi\left( kt + f_{1}\right)\tau\right] \, d\tau
\end{split} \\
\begin{split}
&= \mp \left\lbrace \cancelto{1}{\cos^{2} \left[ 2\pi\left(  \frac{k}{2}t^{2} + f_{1}t + \varphi\right)\right] + \sin^{2} \left[ 2\pi\left(  \frac{k}{2}t^{2} + f_{1}t + \varphi\right)\right]} \right\rbrace \\
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}} \int_{0}^{t} s_{i}\left( \tau\right) \sin \left[ 2\pi\left( kt + f_{1}\right)\tau\right] \, d\tau
\end{split} \\
&= \mp \int_{0}^{t} s_{i}\left( \tau\right) \sin \left[ 2\pi\left( kt + f_{1}\right)\tau\right] \, d\tau
\end{align}
%
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a proposal. The latest version of `tikzmark` has a new command, `\tikzmarkmode`, which has many stunning features, one of which being that it detects the mode you're in. Hence, you do not have to add any `$` nor worry about inline equation vs. display style if you use it. The cancellation can be achieved with a simple path picture.

```
\documentclass[mainlanguage=english,babel={main=english,french,brazil},sepcorpaffilfrench={,~},sepcorpaffilenglish={,~},version=inprogress]{yathesis}
%\documentclass{book}
%\documentclass{article}
%
% If using XeLaTex or LuaLaTex
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%
% If using LaTex or PdfLaTex
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%
\usepackage{lmodern} % latin modern font
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel} % draw diagonal lines  ("cancelling" a term)
%
%%% Code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156581/95438 %%%
%
\usepackage{keycommand}
% Patch by Joseph Wright ("bug in the definition of \ifcommandkey (2010/04/27 v3.1415)"),
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35794
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\catcode`\/=8 %
\@firstofone
{
    \endgroup
    \renewcommand{\ifcommandkey}[1]{%
        \csname @\expandafter \expandafter \expandafter
        \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter
        \kcmd@nbk \commandkey {#1}//{first}{second}//oftwo\endcsname
    }
}
%--------%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}
\newkeycommand{\hcancel}[hshiftstart=0pt,vshiftstart=0pt,hshiftend=0pt,vshiftend=0pt,color=red][1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(tocancel.base)]{
        \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (tocancel) {#1};
        \draw[\commandkey{color}] ($(tocancel.south west)+(\commandkey{hshiftstart},\commandkey{vshiftstart})$) --
        ($(tocancel.north east)+(\commandkey{hshiftend},\commandkey{vshiftend})$);
    }%
}%
\tikzset{cancel/.style={path picture={
\draw[#1] (path picture bounding box.south west) -- 
(path picture bounding box.north east);
}}}
%
%%% End of code %%%
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
&= \mp \cos^{2} \left[ 2\pi\left(  \frac{k}{2}t^{2} + f_{1}t + \varphi\right)\right] \int_{0}^{t} s_{i}\left( \tau\right) \sin \left[ 2\pi\left( kt + f_{1}\right)\tau\right] \, d\tau \\
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}} \cancel{\pm \frac{1}{2} \sin \left[ 4\pi\left(  \frac{k}{2}t^{2} + f_{1}t + \varphi\right)\right] \int_{0}^{t} s_{i}\left( \tau\right) \cos \left[ 2\pi\left( kt + f_{1}\right)\tau\right] \, d\tau} \\
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}} \tikzmarknode[cancel]{cc}{\mp \frac{1}{2} \sin \left[ 4\pi\left(  \frac{k}{2}t^{2} + f_{1}t + \varphi\right)\right] \int_{0}^{t} s_{i}\left( \tau\right) \cos \left[ 2\pi\left( kt + f_{1}\right)\tau\right] \, d\tau} \\
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}} \mp \sin^{2} \left[ 2\pi\left(  \frac{k}{2}t^{2} + f_{1}t + \varphi\right)\right] \int_{0}^{t} s_{i}\left( \tau\right) \sin \left[ 2\pi\left( kt + f_{1}\right)\tau\right] \, d\tau
\end{split} \\
\begin{split}
&= \mp \left\lbrace \cancelto{1}{\cos^{2} \left[ 2\pi\left(  \frac{k}{2}t^{2} + f_{1}t + \varphi\right)\right] + \sin^{2} \left[ 2\pi\left(  \frac{k}{2}t^{2} + f_{1}t + \varphi\right)\right]} \right\rbrace \\
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}} \int_{0}^{t} s_{i}\left( \tau\right) \sin \left[ 2\pi\left( kt + f_{1}\right)\tau\right] \, d\tau
\end{split} \\
&= \tikzmarknode[cancel=red]{cc}{\mp \int_{0}^{t} s_{i}\left( \tau\right) \sin
\left[ 2\pi\left( kt + f_{1}\right)\tau\right] \, d\tau}
\end{align}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Off-topic but I would typeset the differential `d`s that appear in the integrals upright.