# Does the package yathesis support Xelatex?

Tags: yathesis

As the title says. I'm considering to use
different font-faces, so I wonder if it's possible or not,
using XeLatex for example.

Comment: Here there is the documentation: https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/yathesis/doc/yathesis-fr.pdf I not understood the French language :-(

Comment: Me neither, and it seems the package doesn't have that support, I want confirmation.

Comment: If you look this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460267/need-help-to-create-a-more-flexible-cancel-command-that-works-inside-an-align-e yathesis support XeLaTeX (see the code of the question and the answer).

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a good idea to use the class if you can't read the documentation. The class doesn't contain code specific to an engine. So you can use it with xelatex or lualatex but you will have to setup the fonts.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yeah, I am checking other similar classes, do you have any suggestion?