# ConTeXt: Comparing macro result to string

Tags: context

This seems like a very basic question and I'm sure it's been answered somewhere, but I can't find anything on it. The closest I've gotten is [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24922/comparing-an-argument-to-a-string-when-argument-is-a-result-of-a-command-with-et), but neither of the solutions in the accepted answer help my code.

I'm trying to branch based on the value of a namespace parameter. If I replace the `\namedordefaulteraparameter{#1}{formatdecoration}` with a literal `yes`, I get "y" as I'd expect, and just printing the value of that macro also gives me the "yes" it should. However, when I pass the macro to the test, I always get "n". I'm guessing that this is due to `\doifsamestringelse` testing the values without expanding them, but no matter how many `\expandafter`s I use or where I put them, I can't get the first result to be included. What am I missing?

```
\definenamespace[era][
    type=module,
    name=era,
    command=yes,
    setup=yes,
]

\setupera[
    formatdecoration=yes,
]

\define[2]\namedordefaulteraparameter{%
    \doifsomethingelse
        {\namederaparameter{#1}{#2}}
        {\namederaparameter{#1}{#2}}
        {\eraparameter{#2}}%
}

\def\eradecorated[#1]#2{%
    \doifsamestringelse{yes}{\namedordefaulteraparameter{#1}{formatdecoration}}
        {y}
        {n}%
}
```

I know I could do this pretty easily in Lua, but for something so simple, I don't see any reason to add that extra syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several flaws in your example:

1. `\doifsamestringelse` will detokenize both strings and then comapare the result.  You have to use `\doifelse` instead.
2. `\namedordefaulteraparameter` is not expandable, but for `\doifelse` to ever be true both operands must expand to the same result.
3. `\doifsomethingelse` is not expandable.  You have to use the expandable alternative `\expdoifelse`.

Implementing an expandable test and making everything in between expandable as well, we are ready to go.

```
\definenamespace[era][
    type=module,
    name=era,
    command=yes,
    setup=yes,
]

\setupera[
    formatdecoration=yes,
]

\def\namedordefaulteraparameter#1#2{%
    \expdoifelse{\namederaparameter{#1}{#2}}{}%
        {\eraparameter{#2}}%
        {\namederaparameter{#1}{#2}}%
}

\def\eradecorated[#1]#2{%
    \expdoifelse{yes}{\namedordefaulteraparameter{#1}{formatdecoration}}%
        {y}%
        {n}%
}

\starttext

\eradecorated[era]{}

\stoptext
```

Comment: You can replace `\define[2]\...` with `\defineexpandable[2]\...` to create a expandable command.

Comment: @Metafox Which is probably equivalent to `\def...#1#2`.  But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks! It's all working now. The only question that leaves me with is whether there's anywhere that explains all that: the issue with `\define` is touched upon on [its wiki page](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/define), but the only place I saw `\expdoifelse` even mentioned was in [the release notes](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Context_2008.08.04), and that doesn't include any description of what it's for. Are there some other docs I should be looking at, or do I just have to read through the mailing list or something?

Comment: @WovenTales The matter with expandability is more fundamental than ConTeXt.  To learn about it you need to read [The TeXbook](http://a.co/aBVg3ej) (the source is available on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/texbook)).  It is definitely worth it!

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure why you are defining `\namedordefaultparameter`. The standard way to fall back on a default argument is as follows:

```
\definenamespace
  [era]
  [
    type=module,
    name=era,
    command=yes,
    setup=yes,
    parent=era, % NOTE: Added this!!
  ]

\setupera
  [
    formatdecoration=yes,
  ]

\defineera[test1][formatdecoration=no]
\defineera[test2]

\starttext

\namederaparameter{test1}{formatdecoration}
\namederaparameter{test2}{formatdecoration}


\stoptext
```

which gives

```
no yes
```

Based on this, you can define `\eradecorated` macro as follows:

```
\def\eradecorated[#1]%
    {\doifelse{\namederaparameter{#1}{formatdecoration}}{yes}
      {y}{n}}
```

and use it as

```
\eradecorated[test1]
\eradecorated[test2]
```

which gives

```
n y
```

Note that, strictly speaking, the above macro is not equivalent to the one that you defined. If I set `\defineera[test2][formatdefinition=]`, then my macro gives the result `n n`, while you macro still gives the result `n y`. I don't know whether you care about the difference or not.

Comment: I could have sworn that I tried that and found it didn't fall back on the default for some reason. You're right though, it's working now. Thanks for the catch! And I had a note that I needed to fix my macro to give the equivalent of `n n`, so that difference is actually desirable.